# IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9. I am trying to build a sudoku solver that solves it on its own

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, indexing

I am trying to build a sudoku solver in python, but its returning an error "IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9"

```
import numpy as np

x = 0

sudoku = np.zeros((9,9))
running = True
for i in range(9) :
    for j in range(9) :
        x = input("enter the element of {}th row and {}th column [input '0' for blank spaces in the sudoku] : ".format(i+1,j+1))
        if x == "" or type(sudoku[i][j]) == str :
            x = input("enter a number")
        sudoku[i][j] = x

list_row = []
list_column = []
setOfUnion = set()
status = ""
status_list = []
vacancy_numbers = set()
while running :
    for i in range(9) :
        for j in range(9) :

            if sudoku[i][j] in (1,10)  :
                pass
            else :
                list_row = sudoku[i]
                list_column = sudoku[:,j]
                for object in list_row :
                    for object2 in list_column :
                        setOfUnion.add(object)
                        setOfUnion.add(object2)
                        if object == 0 or object2 == 0 :
                            setOfUnion.remove(0)
                        for i in range(1,10) :
                            if i in setOfUnion :
                                pass
                            else :
                                vacancy_numbers.add(i)


                    if len(vacancy_numbers) == 1 :
                        sudoku[i][j] = vacancy_numbers
                        status = "filled"
                        status_list += status
                    else :
                        status = "unfilled"
                        status_list += status
            if status =="filled" :
                break
        if status == "filled" :

            break
    if "filled" in status_list :
        pass
    else :
        running = False

print(sudoku)
```

My code takes a sudoku matrix from the user and checks a row and a column of a block (element in the matrix) and creates a set of other numbers which can be filled in that block, if the length of that set = 1 then it will replace the vacancy spot with the set
It is returning an error :

```
if sudoku[i][j] in (1,10)  :
```

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Comment: line 32: `for i in range(1,10)` is overwriting the `i` from `for i in range(9)`  in line 18. Thus on the second iteration of the `for j in range(9)` loop, `i == 9` and therefore out of bounds. Use a different variable as counter in the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

You have a `for i in range(1, 10)` inside the `for i in range(9)` which causes the inner for loop to overwrite i from the `range(9)` for loop.
You just need to change the variable name of one of them.